# How to set Minimum and Maximum limit to Uitextfield?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uitextfield

i need to set minimum and maximum limit value to one single textfield i.e the number should start with minimum 2 digits and maximum 5 digits here i tried some methods

```
-(BOOL)validatenumber:(NSString*)Number{

if ([Number length ]>=2)  {
    return NO;
}

return YES;
```

}

Comment: You can validate in the textfield delegate methods. Look under the managing editing section. https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/index.html

Comment: can u give some sample code dude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{

NSInteger inte = [textField.text intValue];
if (inte <5 && inte > 2)

    return NO;
else 
    return YES;
}
```

**Swift**

```
override func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
var inte: Int = CInt(textField.text!)!
if inte < 5 && inte > 2 {
    return false
}
else {
    return true
}
}
```

Comment: r u calculating the range of textfield na

Comment: @HariNarayanan - this question is not a common based on question request I answered what the scenario you working and what the issue u faced

Comment: - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {     i am used this method for calculating the range but when i am used - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{ its not working

Comment: @HariNarayanan - I am not added this scenario

Comment: @HariNarayanan - you need answer like in `shouldChangeCharacte‌`

Comment: @HariNarayanan - you need the same answer in shouldChangeCharacte‌​rsInRange:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121150/discussion-between-hari-narayanan-and-anbu-karthik).

Answer (score 2):

Try this out with slight modifications as per your need. This will also handle the deletion of first element in textfield to set the minimum value and will not allow to enter less than minimum value or more than maximum value.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if let manualInputText = textField.text, let range = Range(range, in: manualInputText) {

        let inputText = manualInputText.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
        let minValue = 0 //your value
        let maxValue = 10 //your value

        if inputText.isEmpty {
            textField.text = "\(minValue)"
            return false
        } else if textField.text == "0" {
            textField.text = string
            return false
        }
        if let inputValue = Int64(inputText), (inputValue >= minValue), (inputValue <= maxValue) {
                return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Please comment if you need any modifications.

Comment: this always returns false?

Answer (score 1):

```
if ([amount.text length]>=2 && [amount.text length]<=5) {
    }else{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"error" message:@"Plz enter the amout Min 10Rs" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first check that you can parse a number from your string, and then check the range of the number

```
-(BOOL)validatenumber:(NSString*)Number{

    NSCharacterSet *characterSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789,."] invertedSet];
    if ([Number rangeOfCharacterFromSet:characterSet].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        return NO;
    }

    return ([Number intValue] >= 100 && [Number intValue] <= 99999);
}
```

Set the delegate to your UITextField. And run validate when the user finishes editing your UITextField in function `func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField)`. Present a popup alert to the user if validation fails

Comment: thanx for the reply @anthonyliao but this method not working, actually in that amount text field user have to enter min 10RS and max 99999Rs thats it if user enter below 10rs and above the max value means i have to show alert view

Comment: if (![self validateTopUpAmpont:amount.text]) {
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"error" message:@"Plz enter the amout Min 10Rs" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        return;
    }

Comment: Have you set `textField.delegate = self`?