# How to set the maximum number of value during typing

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have a UITextField, I'd like to restrict the maximum allowed input value in the field to be 1000 .eg (1-1000),If the value in the textfield exceeds above 1000 the textfield should not get the value as input.I have tried the following

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField,shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange,replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{
    var newString: String = textField.text.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
    var characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789,.").inverted
    if (newString as NSString).rangeOfCharacter(from: characterSet).location != NSNotFound {
        return false
    }
    return Double(newString) ?? 0.0 < 1000
}
```

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31363216/set-the-maximum-character-length-of-a-uitextfield-in-swift

Comment: ya your condition is statisfy only = 999 chars and if it is exceed is returns false

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik the text field should get values from 1- 1000 , above 1000 is not accepted (eg-1001) should not be accepted

Comment: ya its correct , what you expect

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik the answer I have posted is correct ? or the link you have mentioned is correct?

Comment: both are correct, by default your condition > 1001 the textfield should not allow it returns false

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782982/how-to-input-currency-format-on-a-text-field-from-right-to-left-using-swift/29783546?s=1|17.2382#29783546

Comment: Use key-value validation as intended by @Anbu.Karthik.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I don't know where I am wrong but still I am unable to achieve what I am expecting, Can you please attach a working code for swift 4?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Hope this will help

```
 func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        guard let text = textField.text else { return true }
        let newLength = text.characters.count + string.characters.count - range.length
        return newLength <= 1001 
    }
```

Comment: OP wants to limit the value not the number of characters

Answer (score 0):

Try extracting the integer value from the textField and check if it is below 1000.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
  {
      NSInteger inte = [textField.text intValue];
      if (inte < 1000 && inte > 0)
         return NO;
      else 
         return YES;
  }
```

Comment: OP is working with Double not Integers and the question is tagged as Swift.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26582453/how-to-set-minimum-and-maximum-limit-to-uitextfield
You can check this link

Comment: It doesn't make any difference